# Meteor Upgrade to 1.3 - no method found error

Tags: meteor

Hi I'm upgrading to Meteor 1.3 and am getting alot of errors on my packages relating to an add_file method.

In all my packages (uikit for example) it's no longer recognizing this method (I assume).

Anyone run into this?

Errors:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'add_file'
at package.js:12:7
at __bottom_mark__ (/tools/utils/parse-stack.js:59:14)
at PackageSource.initFromPackageDir (/tools/isobuild/package-source.js:1046:9)
at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-local.js:286:23
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:359:18
at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:352:34
at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:350:23
at [object Object].withValue (/tools/utils/fiber-helpers.js:89:14)
at Object.enterJob (/tools/utils/buildmessage.js:324:26)
at initSourceFromDir (/tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-local.js:273:20)
at /tools/packaging/catalog/catalog-local.js:346:9
at /tools/utils/buildmessage.js:565:21
at /Users/chazmee/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.0_3.1b03du5++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/isopackets/ddp/npm/node_modules/meteor/promise/node_modules/meteor-promise/fiber_pool.js:33:40
```

Update to release METEOR@1.3 is impossible:

```
While reading package from `/Users/chazmee/placelist/packages/uikit-2`:
```

package.js:12:7: Object [object Object] has no method 'add_file'

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder if that is a deprecated method name. See if `api.addFiles()` fixes it

Comment: AWESOME. Worked. thanks!

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`api.add_file()` in your Meteor packages should be updated to `api.addFiles()`.